# add password step in image steganogrpahy

Tags: java, image-processing, steganography

i can hide image inside another and reveal the original, but now in need to add password to the process

```
public BufferedImage encodeImage(String key, BufferedImage cover, BufferedImage secret) {
    int height = secret.getHeight();
    int width = secret.getWidth();
    byte[] bytes = getImageBytes(secret);
    bytes = encrypt(bytes, key.getBytes());
    // get byte array for width, height, and message (8 bytes = 1 bit)
    byte[] widthArray = getBytesFromInt(WIDTH_BITS/8, width);
    byte[] heightArray = getBytesFromInt(HEIGHT_BITS/8, height);
    byte[] messageLengthArray = getBytesFromInt(MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS/8, bytes.length);

    byte[] imageArray = getImageBytes(cover);

    // hide bytes with offset of previous bit lengths added up
    hideBytes(imageArray, messageLengthArray, 0);
    hideBytes(imageArray, widthArray, MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS);
    hideBytes(imageArray, heightArray, MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS + WIDTH_BITS);
    hideBytes(imageArray, bytes, MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS + WIDTH_BITS + HEIGHT_BITS);

    return cover;
}
```

but I can't use the same process to retrieve the secret image

Update:
but I can't use the same process to retrieve the secret image

```
   public BufferedImage decodeImage(String key, BufferedImage bimg) {
        byte[] imageArray = getImageBytes(bimg);
        int length = 0, height = 0, width = 0;

        // loop through all encoded length bits and store value in corresponding variable
        for (int i = 0; i < (MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS + WIDTH_BITS + HEIGHT_BITS); i++) {
            if (i < MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS)
                length = (length << 1) | (imageArray[i] & 1);
            else if (i < MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS + WIDTH_BITS)
                width = (width << 1) | (imageArray[i] & 1);
            else
                height = (height << 1) | (imageArray[i] & 1);
        }

        byte[] result = new byte[length];

        // skip all encoded lengths (message_length, width and height bits)
        int index = MESSAGE_LENGTH_BITS + WIDTH_BITS + HEIGHT_BITS;

        // loop til length of message and grab each LSB from image
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) { // each bit
                // shift by 1 and grab last bit of next image byte
                result[i] = (byte) ((result[i] << 1) | (imageArray[index] & 1));
                index++;
            }
        }

        // swap blue with red to follow RGB sequence from BGR
        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i+=3) {
            byte temp = result[i];
            result[i] = result[i+2];
            result[i+2] = temp;
        }


        // create image
        BufferedImage b = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
        WritableRaster raster = b.getRaster();
        raster.setDataElements(0, 0, width, height, result);

        return b;
    }
```

the password process is only XOR the data with the secret image

```
public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] key, byte[] plainText) {
    byte[] result = new byte[plainText.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < plainText.length; i++) {
        result[i] = (byte) (plainText[i] ^ key[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The other methods in the process
hide method and int to bytes and get bytes from image

```
private void hideBytes(byte[] bimg, byte[] bytes, int offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        int character = bytes[i];
        for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {  // 8 bits per character
            // get corresponding bit
            int bit = (character >> j) & 1;

            // get last image byte, set last bit to 0 ( AND 0xFE) then OR with bit
            bimg[offset] = (byte) ((bimg[offset] & 0xFE) | bit);
            offset++;
        }
    }
}

    private byte[] getBytesFromInt(int size, int number) {
    byte[] b = new byte[size];

    for (int i = size-1, shift = 0; i >= 0; i--, shift += 8)
        b[i] = (byte) ((number & (0x000000FF << shift)) >> shift);

    return b;
}

private byte[] getImageBytes(BufferedImage bimg) {
    WritableRaster raster = bimg.getRaster();
    DataBufferByte dbb = (DataBufferByte) raster.getDataBuffer();
    return dbb.getData();
}
```

Comment: You claim you can embed and extract a secret. Therefore, unless you've changed your code (I imagine `bytes` is either the original image bytes or the encrypted ones so there is no other change), your problem lies in the encryption and decryption functions. This is what we need to see, unless you've established that bytes == `decrypt(encrypt(bytes))`.

Comment: On a less relevant note, when you embed the raw pixels + height + width, it's like hiding a bmp image, which is uncompressed. Since all you hide is bytes, you can simply read the bytestream of any file as is.

Comment: After get every lsb , then get the original by xor with the password but alwas get error main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 23


`private static String pwd = "the password ya geddaan";`

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The error you get is super important and you should post the complete traceback. I don't see that string anywhere used in your code or how it's used, but as the error suggests, you've probably messed up the indexing in a loop or something.